# Using colClasses and select arguments of fread simultaneously

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to load in a small number of fields from a tab-separated file with many more unused fields using `fread` in the `data.table` package.

To this end, I'm using the `select` option, which works great for reading in the columns.

However, when I don't specify the classes of the various fields, the automated selector doesn't work (most/all of the numeric variables end up being read as numerically tiny numbers like `1.896916e-316`).

To fix this, my first instinct was to change the code from:

```
DT <- fread("data.txt", select = c ("V1", "V2", ..., "Vn"))
```

to

```
DT <- fread("data.txt", select = c("V1", "V2", ..., "Vn"),
            colClasses = c("numeric", ..., "character"))
```

i.e., to match the `select` character vector with a `colClasses` character vector of equal length, with (obviously) the type of the i-th selected field from select set equal to the i-th element of `colClasses`.

However, `fread` doesn't seem to like this--even when `select` is used, `colClasses` expects a character vector with as many fields as the WHOLE file:

> Error in `fread("data.txt", select = c("V1", "V2", ..., "Vn",`  : 
>   `colClasses` is unnamed and length 25 but there are 256 columns. See
>   `?data.table` for `colClasses` usage.

This could be fine if I only had to do this with one file--I'd simply pad out the rest of the character vector with `"character"` (or whatever type) because they're being tossed anyway.

However, I'm planning to repeat this process 13 times or so on files corresponding to other years--they have the same column names, but appear in perhaps different orders (and there are different numbers of columns from year to year), which ruins the loop-ability (as well as taking a lot more time).

The following worked, but hardly seems efficient (coding-wise):

```
DT <- fread("data.txt", select=c("V1", "V2", "V3"),
            colClasses = c(V1 = "factor", V2 = "character", V3 = "numeric"))
```

This is a pain because I'm taking 25 columns, so it's a huge block of code being taken up by specifying the column types. I can't take advantage of `rep` to save space, e.g.

```
colClasses = c(rep("character", times = 3), rep("numeric", times = 20))
```

Any suggestions for making this look/work better?

Here is a preview of the data for reference:

```
         LEAID FIPST                                                   NAME SCHLEV AGCHRT CCDNF GSLO   V33  TOTALREV  TFEDREV
    1: 0100002    01                                 ALABAMA YOUTH SERVICES      N      3     1   03     0        -2       -2
    2: 0100005    01                                       ALBERTVILLE CITY     03      3     1   PK  4143  38394000  6326000
    3: 0100006    01                                        MARSHALL COUNTY     03      3     1   PK  5916  58482000 11617000
    4: 0100007    01                                            HOOVER CITY     03      3     1   PK 13232 154703000 10184000
    5: 0100008    01                                           MADISON CITY     03      3     1   PK  8479  89773000  6648000
---                                                                                                                       
18293: 5680180    56                                NORTHEAST WYOMING BOCES     07      3     1    N    -2        -2       -2
18294: 5680250    56                                         REGION V BOCES     07      3     1    N    -2        -2       -2
18295: 5680251    56                  WYOMING DEPARTMENT OF FAMILY SERVICES     02      3     1   KG    82        -2       -2
18296: 5680252    56 YOUTH EMERGENCY SERVICES, INC. - ADMINISTRATION OFFICE      N      3     1   07    29        -1       -1
18297: 5680253    56                           WYOMING BEHAVIORAL INSTITUTE      N      N     1   01     0        -2       -2
```

Comment: I thought there was a mechanism for "NULL" arguments in colClasses, thereby obviating the need for select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually found a solution in a more careful reading of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699816/using-colclasses-in-fread?rq=1) illustration of the `drop`/`select`/`colClasses` options by Mr. Dowle:

```
DT <- fread("data.txt", select = c("V1", "V2", "V3"),
            colClasses = list(character = c("char_names"),
                              factor = c("factor_names"),
                              numeric = c("numeric_names")))
```

I didn't realize this before because there were some other problems with my `fread` attempts due to bad formatting of my .csv file.

Still, I am wont to call it a bug that the natural approach doesn't work:

```
DT <- fread("data.txt", select = c("V1", ..., "Vn"),
            colClasses = c("type1", ..., "typen"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something along these lines:

```
 varnames <- readLines(file='filename.txt', n=1)
 valid <- c("LEAID", "FIPST", "NAME", "SCHLEV", "AGCHRT", "CCDNF", "GSLO", "V33", "TOTALREV", "TFEDREV")
 colC <- varnames %in% valid 
 colCchar <- colC
 colCchar[!colC] <-"NULL"
 colCchar[colC] <- c( rep("numeric", 2), rep("character",2),  
                      rep("numeric", 2), "character",
                      rep("numeric", 3) )
 dt<-fread("data.txt", colClasses=colCchar)
```

Obviously untested since the 200+ first line was not provided. It won't be stable to variation in order of variables in the targets,  but your problem description did "leave something to be desired". I cannot quite figure out how the column names would be the same but would vary. You may need to use `match` to get the order of the desired variables.