# Have a double column be a character column when loading data in R

Tags: r, data.table, double, character

I am trying to load a database

There is a column which contains quite long strings which correspond to code numbers (for instance 078000000000000000)

When I load the data, R turns these numbers into double (so 7,8 E+15)

If I try to turn it into a character with `as.character`, it simply becomes "7,8 E+15" so I still lose information

By the way, when loading the data I'm using :

```
my_data <- fread(file)
```

And the data is correct, although there is this type problem

Comment: I think you can use the colClasses argument in fread, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699816/using-colclasses-in-fread)

Comment: If you don't want to drop the leading 0, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699816/using-colclasses-in-fread) on using `colClasses` in `fread`.

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation. data.table can read in 64bit integers if you install the bit64 package.

```
install.packages("bit64")
fread("078000000000000000
      ")
#                  V1
#1: 78000000000000000
```

Or for importing as characters:

```
fread("078000000000000000
      ", colClasses = "character")
#                   V1  
#1: 078000000000000000
```