# Turn numbers into integer with fread function when loading data

Tags: r, data.table

I used `fread` to load csv file as the following line.

```
data_startle <- fread('Materials/data/1/1.EMG.csv')
```

Figure 1 is what it looked like after loading into R and figure 2 is what it looked like in the file.

Can I make it the same in R as in EXCEL? All numbers in the last few columns should be integer.

[image: Figure 1]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your input file with a text editor (such as Notepad)? Are you sure that they are integers? Are you also sure none of these values exceed the integer range?

Comment: @Roland Can I make numbers in R like 0001,000 as 1? I need to make it the same as in EXCEL to match my another data set.

Comment: You can, but first define what “same” means to you. You should care about the internal representation of numbers but you seem to be focused on how numbers are displayed. Why is that?

Comment: Sorry I already assumed that there is a problem so haven't done my next step. So if 0001,000 and 1 mean the same to R, I am still able to match the two columns despite of different number display?

Comment: R will coerce types as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fread` function has an argument `colClasses` which you can use to specify data types of specific columns, e.g.:

```
data_startle <- fread('Materials/data/1/1.EMG.csv', colClasses=list(integer=c("practise","acq")))
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699816/using-colclasses-in-fread) post for more details.